# Java - Count exactly 60 characters from a string with a mixture of UTF-8 and non UTF-8 characters

Tags: java, string, oracle, encoding, character-encoding

I have a string which i want to save in a database that only supports UTF8 characters.  If the string size is > 60 characters i want to truncate it and only store the first 60 characters. The Oracle database in use only supports UTF-8 characters.

Using `String.substring(0,59)` in Java returns 60 characters but when i save it in the database it gets rejected as the database claims that the string is > 60 characters.

- Is there a way to find out if a particular string contains non UTF8 characters. One option i found is:

  `try {`

  ```
      bytes = returnString.getBytes("UTF-8");


  } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
      // Do something
  ```

  `}`
- is there a way i can truncate it to exactly x number of characters (loss of data is not an issue) and make sure that when saved in the database only x number of characters are saved. For example if i have the string `Â§8Â§8Â§8Â§8Â§8Â§8Â§8` and i say truncate and save only 5 characters it should only save `Â§8Â§`

Comment: "I have a string which contains a mixture of UTF-8 and non UTF-8 characters." There's no such thing. *All* characters in Java are stored as UTF-16, and every valid character can be represented in UTF-8. It's very unclear what you actually mean.

Comment: Ok thats how they are represented in Java, but when i store the string in Oracle it is not longer UTF-16 (if the character set configured in Oracle is UTF-8) right ?

Comment: But that doesn't mean that your question makes any sense. There's really no such thing as "a UTF-8 character". UTF-8 is an encoding, that's all.

Comment: You should decide whether “70 characters” or “60 characters”; both appear two times in your question. I used `60` in my answer…

Comment: @Jon Skeet - What do you mean by "every valid character"? Could you give an example of an invalid character

Comment: @ziggy: For example, if you had a string containing just one half of a  surrogate pair. That would be a sequence of UTF-16 code units that didn't actually represent a valid sequence of Unicode characters.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I understand you want to limit the `String` length in a way that the encoded `UTF-8` representation does not exceed 60 bytes. You can do it this way:

```
String s=…;
CharsetEncoder enc=StandardCharsets.UTF_8.newEncoder();
ByteBuffer bb=ByteBuffer.allocate(60);// note the limit
CharBuffer cb = CharBuffer.wrap(s);
CoderResult r = enc.encode(cb, bb, true);
if(r.isOverflow()) {
    System.out.println(s+" is too long for "
                      +bb.capacity()+" "+enc.charset()+" bytes");
    s=cb.flip().toString();
    System.out.println("truncated to "+s);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my quick hack: a function to truncate a string to given number of bytes in UTF-8 encoding:

```
public static String truncateUtf8(String original, int byteCount) {
    if (original.length() * 3 <= byteCount) {
        return original;
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < original.length(); i++) {
        char c = original.charAt(i);
        int newCount;
        if (c <= 0x7f) newCount = count + 1;
        else if (c <= 0x7ff) newCount = count + 2;
        else newCount = count + 3;
        if (newCount > byteCount) {
            break;
        }
        count = newCount;
        sb.append(c);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

It does not work as expected for characters outside of BMP – counts them as 6 bytes instead of 4. It may also break grapheme clusters. But for most simple tasks it should be OK.

```
truncateUtf8("e", 1) => "e"
truncateUtf8("ée", 1) => ""
truncateUtf8("ée", 2) => "é"
truncateUtf8("ée", 3) => "ée"
```